# Qt 4.6.2 with VS 2005 on windows 7 -- Unknown error Qmake failed

Tags: qt4

I am trying to configure Qt 4.6.2 commercial version for visual studio 2005 professional VC. I am new to Qt. When I try to configure it on cmd I get the following error(s)

I have installed windows SDK (which is supposed to to cover directshow/directX).

Error I am getting:

```
Do you accept the terms of the license?
y
All the required DirectShow/Direct3D files couldn't be found.
Make sure you have either the platform SDK AND the DirectShow SDK or the Windows
 SDK installed.
If you have the DirectShow SDK installed, please make sure that you have run the
 <path to SDK>\SetEnv.Cmd script.
vmr9.h not found
dshow.h not found
strmiids.lib not found
dmoguids.lib not found
msdmo.lib not found
d3d9.h not found
Environment:
    INCLUDE=
      Unset
    LIB=
      Unset
    PATH=
      C:\Windows\system32
      C:\Windows
      C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
      C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
      C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\runtime\win32
      C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\bin
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\
      D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\runtime\win32
      D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\bin
      C:\Qt\4.6.2\bin
      D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin

Licensee....................Ali
License ID..................1517430
Product license.............FullFramework Edition
Expiry Date.................

Configuration:
    minimal-config
    small-config
    medium-config
    large-config
    full-config
    build_all
    debug
Qt Configuration:
    release
    debug
    zlib
    png
    accessibility
    qt3support
    opengl
    s60
    ipv6
    script
    scripttools
    xmlpatterns
    multimedia
    audio-backend
    webkit
    native-gestures
    svg
    minimal-config
    small-config
    medium-config
    large-config
    full-config

QMAKESPEC...................win32-msvc2005 (detected)
Architecture................windows
Maketool....................nmake
Debug symbols...............yes
Link Time Code Generation...no
Accessibility support.......yes
STL support.................yes
Exception support...........yes
RTTI support................yes
MMX support.................yes
3DNOW support...............no
SSE support.................yes
SSE2 support................yes
IWMMXT support..............no
OpenGL support..............yes
OpenVG support..............no
OpenSSL support.............no
QtDBus support..............no
QtXmlPatterns support.......yes
Phonon support..............no
QtMultimedia support........yes
WebKit support..............yes
Declarative support.........no
QtScript support............yes
QtScriptTools support.......yes
Graphics System.............raster
Qt3 compatibility...........yes

Third Party Libraries:
    ZLIB support............qt
    GIF support.............plugin
    TIFF support............plugin
    JPEG support............plugin
    PNG support.............qt
    MNG support.............plugin
    FreeType support........no

Styles:
    Windows.................yes
    Windows XP..............no
    Windows Vista...........no
    Plastique...............yes
    Cleanlooks..............yes
    Motif...................yes
    CDE.....................yes
    Windows CE..............no
    Windows Mobile..........no
    S60.....................no

Sql Drivers:
    ODBC....................no
    MySQL...................no
    OCI.....................no
    PostgreSQL..............no
    TDS.....................no
    DB2.....................no
    SQLite..................plugin (qt)
    SQLite2.................no
    InterBase...............no

Sources are in..............C:\Qt\4.6.2
Build is done in............C:\Qt\4.6.2
Install prefix..............C:\Qt\4.6.2
Headers installed to........C:\Qt\4.6.2\include
Libraries installed to......C:\Qt\4.6.2\lib
Plugins installed to........C:\Qt\4.6.2\plugins
Binaries installed to.......C:\Qt\4.6.2\bin
Docs installed to...........C:\Qt\4.6.2\doc
Data installed to...........C:\Qt\4.6.2
Translations installed to...C:\Qt\4.6.2\translations
Examples installed to.......C:\Qt\4.6.2\examples
Demos installed to..........C:\Qt\4.6.2\demos

Symbian DEF files enabled...yes
Creating qmake...

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Creating makefiles in src...
Generating Visual Studio project files...
execute: Unknown error
   (-nodepend)
   (-tp)
   (vc)
   (-spec)
   (win32-msvc2005)
   (-r)
   (C:/Qt/4.6.2/projects.pro)
   (-o)
   (C:/Qt/4.6.2)
Qmake failed, return code -1

Generating Makefiles...
execute: Unknown error
   (-spec)
   (win32-msvc2005)
   (-r)
   (C:/Qt/4.6.2/projects.pro)
   (-o)
   (C:/Qt/4.6.2)
Qmake failed, return code -1
```

Comment: Did you try running that SetEnv.cmd? Or, if you don't have it, you probably need to specify INCLUDEPATH+=... and LIBS+=... arguments to qmake.

Answer (score 1):

I had to copy qmake.exe from qmake subfolder to bin subfolder.
Using Qt 4.8.0 with Visual Studio 2008 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

It fails while creating Visual Studio project files, as a workaround add the following parameters to `configure.exe`

```
--no-vcproj --no-dsp
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Still getting the "not found" error.